# Cucumber features time out with "ChildProcess::TimeoutError: process still alive after 90 seconds"

Tags: cucumber

Some of the features in my cucumber suite fail with "ChildProcess::TimeoutError: process still alive after 90 seconds". They seemingly have nothing to do with each other, but all the features that fail have "Tag: @@javascript" listed at the top. I'm not sure why there are two @ signs.